# Clang error: calling a private constructor while none of them were actually called

Tags: c++, clang, copy-constructor, clang++, copy-elision

I made a static function of some class, and made constructor private. Now I want to use the function. Clang++ says "The constructor is private", while g++ compiles normally.

I don't know if there are any rules in any Standard which could affect this in any way. Any function **can** make a variable and there isn't and way it couldn't return a value. So there shouldn't be any errors with `MyStruct::make` in the code above, right? But Clang feels differently about that.

Is this what Clang should make doable or is this that sort of thing that should never be done in C++?

I've tried to make C++ be a little more like Rust here, so that I could never do something unexpected with constructors. I used g++ and the following code works.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <utility>

class MyStruct {
public:
  static auto make(int val) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct that(val);
    return that;
  };

  auto copy() -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct copy(this->val);
    return copy;
  }

  auto value() -> int { return this->val; }

private:
  MyStruct() = delete;

  MyStruct(int val) { this->val = val; }

  MyStruct(const MyStruct &other) { this->val = other.val; }

  int val;
};

auto main() -> int {
  auto my_struct = MyStruct::make(4);

  auto my_new_struct = my_struct.copy();

  std::cout << my_new_struct.value();
  std::cout << MyStruct::make(7).value();
}
```

With Clang, however, I've encountered some errors:

```
main.cpp:30:20: error: calling a private constructor of class 'MyStruct'
  auto my_struct = MyStruct::make(4);
                   ^
main.cpp:24:3: note: declared private here
  MyStruct(const MyStruct &other) { this->val = other.val; }
  ^
main.cpp:32:24: error: calling a private constructor of class 'MyStruct'
  auto my_new_struct = my_struct.copy();
                       ^
main.cpp:24:3: note: declared private here
  MyStruct(const MyStruct &other) { this->val = other.val; }
  ^
2 errors generated.
```

In other words, is this what Clang should make doable or is this that sort of thing that should never be done in C++, and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally for example in this line

```
auto my_struct = MyStruct::make(4);
```

there should be used the copy construtor if not take into account the copy/move elision.

Before the C++ 17 Standard the copy constructor shall be acceptable even if its call is elided.

From the C++ 14 Standard( 12.8 Copying and moving class objects)

> 32. ... [*Note*: This two-stage overload resolution must be performed regardless of whether copy elision will occur. It determines the
>     constructor to be called if elision is not performed, **and the
>     selected constructor must be accessible even if the call is elided**.
>     — *end note* ]

Either make the copy constructor public or switch on the support of at least the C++ 17 Standard.

Comment: This is amazing. It makes a perfect sense, but it's very surprising. It's strange I didn't think about that move semantics was not in C++ earlier. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is depending upon your compiler version and compiler flags.

For Clang version 5.0.1, the code is compiling with [C++17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B17) (compiler switch [`-std=c++17`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-std)), but not on [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (compiler switch [`-std=c++11`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-std)).

[See here that the code is compiling](https://godbolt.org/z/934Mo4o8n) with `-std=c++17` set. But [it is failing to compile the same code](https://godbolt.org/z/9eMbscPsT) if we set `-std=c++11`.